# How to get clubbed result from 2 combo box list in same range of excel

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript, vb6

If there are 2 ComboBox lists I want clubbed results I mean to say the next code for Combobox 2 should only change the status which is having NA status, not for "Newp" or modification, also how to give priority to "Newp" status, e.g. in the case of "Cor" cell should have status "Newp" in clubbed results for range `G7:G19`

```
Set cellRange = Range("G7:G19")

If Not ComboBox1.ListIndex = -1 Then

        Select Case ComboBox1.Value

Case "Baffles"
     cellRange.Find("Baf").EntireRow.Columns("H").Value = "Newp"
     cellRange.Find("Cond").EntireRow.Columns("H").Value = "Modification"
     cellRange.Find("Cor").EntireRow.Columns("H").Value = "Newp"
     cellRange.Find("ManLH").EntireRow.Columns("H").Value = "Modification"
     cellRange.Find("Man RH").EntireRow.Columns("H").Value = "Modification"
     cellRange.Find("Flan").EntireRow.Columns("H").Value = "NA"
     cellRange.Find("Fin ").EntireRow.Columns("H").Value = "NA"
     cellRange.Find("Other com").EntireRow.Columns("H").Value = "NA"
         End Select
       End If   


Set cellRange = Range("G7:G19")

If Not ComboBox2.ListIndex = -1 Then

        Select Case ComboBox2.Value

Case "Cond"
     cellRange.Find("Baf").EntireRow.Columns("H").Value = "Modification"
     cellRange.Find("Cond").EntireRow.Columns("H").Value = "Newp"
     cellRange.Find("Cor").EntireRow.Columns("H").Value = "Modification"
     cellRange.Find("ManLH").EntireRow.Columns("H").Value = "NA"
     cellRange.Find("Man RH").EntireRow.Columns("H").Value = "NA"
     cellRange.Find("Flan").EntireRow.Columns("H").Value = "NA"
     cellRange.Find("Fin ").EntireRow.Columns("H").Value = "NA"
     cellRange.Find("Other com").EntireRow.Columns("H").Value = "NA"
         End Select
       End If
```

Comment: Can you [edit] to clarify exactly what the problem is? Your question is currently not very clear.

Comment: I m using a dropdown list to select components & to change its status & for the same components another dropdown list but when i select two different components few components in them are same for ex in case of "Cond"  and case "baffles" baf is having same, here what i want is clubbed result for 2combolist, i mean to say if Baf has already got status modifcation the next combo code shud not change the status of Baf again or if in both case baf has modification status and newp then it shud make status priority to newp..

Answer (score 0):

your question narrative and code doesn't match exactly your comment

sticking to the former you may be after this:

```
With Range("G7:G19")
    If Not ComboBox1.ListIndex = -1 Then
        Select Case ComboBox1.Value
            Case "Baffles"
                 .Find("Baf").EntireRow.Columns("H").Value = "Newp"
                 .Find("Cond").EntireRow.Columns("H").Value = "Modification"
                 .Find("Cor").EntireRow.Columns("H").Value = "Newp"
                 .Find("ManLH").EntireRow.Columns("H").Value = "Modification"
                 .Find("Man RH").EntireRow.Columns("H").Value = "Modification"
                 .Find("Flan").EntireRow.Columns("H").Value = "NA"
                 .Find("Fin ").EntireRow.Columns("H").Value = "NA"
                 .Find("Other com").EntireRow.Columns("H").Value = "NA"
        End Select
    End If

    If Not ComboBox2.ListIndex = -1 Then
        Select Case ComboBox2.Value
            Case "Cond"
                Process2ndTime .Find("Baf").EntireRow.Columns("H"), "Modification"
                Process2ndTime .Find("Cond").EntireRow.Columns("H"), "Newp"
                Process2ndTime .Find("Cor").EntireRow.Columns("H"), "Modification"
                Process2ndTime .Find("ManLH").EntireRow.Columns("H"), "NA"
                Process2ndTime .Find("Man RH").EntireRow.Columns("H"), "NA"
                .Find("Flan").EntireRow.Columns("H") = "NA"
                .Find("Fin ").EntireRow.Columns("H") = "NA"
                .Find("Other com").EntireRow.Columns("H") = "NA"
        End Select
    End If
End With
```

where you'd use:

```
Sub Process2ndTime(rng As Range, valToSet As String)
    With rng
        If .Value = "NA" Or valToSet = "Newp" Then .Value = valToSet
    End With
End Sub
```

as you see I left last thee statements of `Case "Cond"` without call to `Process2ndTime()` because it seems to me it'd fit your actual need. Should not it be the case then just change these last three lines as the previous five

Comment: @swapnilbhalerao, did you get through it?

Comment: @swapnilbhalerao, it'd be nice of you giving feedback to people trying at helping you. Thank you!

Comment: If cellRange.Find("Baffles").EntireRow.Columns("H").Value = "NA" Then cellRange.Find("Baffles").EntireRow.Columns("H").Value = "New part"